# Dynamically load data / load data from reference (dynamic filtering)

Tags: angular, typescript, environment-variables, devextreme

So I got my `environment.ts` that holds my app configuration. Now I want to add filtering presets to the config, so I can specify different presets for different customers. I'm using: https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Components/dxFilterBuilder/ to create the filter:

[image]

So lets say I want to display a list of employees, instead of "Category", "Unit Price" and "Shipped". This list is only obtainable via an API. How can I save a "reference" in the config to the service that can provide the list of employees?

The usecase of the reference would be when the user opens up the filtering page, the config gets loaded, then the reference of the function would be executed and the api sends back the list of employees, to display in the filtering.

The data should only be loaded, if the user has permissions to access the filtering page. So the data cannot be loaded "before the app starts", because the user is not logged in and has no permissions to get the data from the api.

**environment.ts**

```
export const environment = {
  productName: 'test',
  production: false,
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

environment.ts is for some basic data that application deal with it and may vary between local or publish environments. it is not a good place to put user-specific data here.

consider to create a user-setting service (for example) or even use [ngrx](https://ngrx.io/) for state management and then you can set or get these data, also you may want to save these configurations in localStorage or store them in the backend to save them between refreshes.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please mention the right intention? I am not getting why you want to mix up logic with environment.ts file.

Comment: Yes sure. I got a notification system in my project. You can setup different filters, so you only get notified for those filters. Now those filters need to be customer specific, because some customers cannot use all filters.

Comment: dear @Nikhil-V-S, questions like this to clarify the subject should ask in the comments of the question, not as an answer.

Comment: I know @Mazdak. I was eager to help answering the question. But I didnt have the option to comment on the first time, thats why I did like this. Will keep that in min, thanks.